# MailCore2を利用し、icloud.comのアカウントのメール送信した際に宛先にメールが届かない

Tags: swift, ios

もし、同じなような経験をされた方がおられましたら、情報のご提供もしくは、対策につきまして
ご教授いただけませんでしょうか？

[開発環境]
MailCore2 ver.0.6.4
iOS12.2（iPhone5S）
Swift4.2

[現象]
上記の環境でicloud.comのアカウントを利用してメールを送信した際、
SMTP接続エラーは発生しないが、宛先へメールが届かない。

iPhone実機を利用するとメールが届かない。
但し、シュミレーターではメールが届く。
また、icloud.com以外のメールアカウントを利用すると送信できる。

接続のログは、シュミレーターもiPhone実機も同じ。
（実機のログはシュミレーターより各行に改行が余分に出力される。）

[見解]
宛先になっているメールサーバーのログには届いた記録がないので、
icloudのサーバーでブロックされているようにも見える。

開発途中なので、一度TestFlightで内部テストしてみたが、同じ結果でした。

AppStoreからメールアプリをインストールし同じicloudアカウントを設定すると
問題なく送受信できます。

作成中のアプリの内容にも問題があるかもしれないのですが、自己解決できない状態です。

Comment: 経路中のどこかのメールサーバでブロックされているんでしょうが、「icloudのサーバーで」かどうかは何とも言えないような気がします。最近のメールサーバは攻撃者に余分な情報を与えないため、本当ならエラーのはずの送信要求に「SMTP接続エラーは発生しない」こともよくありますし。全く同じ原因でメールが届かない事態を経験した人が現れない限り、解決は難しそうに思うのですが、念のため確認事項を。**icloud.comのアカウントを利用して** とありますが、正しく[このページ](https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/HT202304)にある設定(送信メールサーバの SMTP 情報)でメール送信していますか?(特にパスワード) **メールの送信者アドレス** は「icloud.comのアカウント」に対応するものになっていますか? どちらも問題ないなら、[こっちのページ](https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/HT203528)にある[問い合わせ先](https://support.apple.com/country-selector/icloud)に問い合わせてみるといいかもしれません。(過去の経験から言うと大きな期待はしない方が良いですが。)

Comment: ありがとうございます。紹介いただいたサイトの内容を確認し（パスワードも生成し）接続を行うようにしていたのですが、このような現象になっております。やはり調査は難しいですよね・・・。確かに、経路の途中で止まっている可能性も高いですよね・・・。一応、Appleへも問い合わせはしているのですが、どこまで対応してもらえるか不安でしたので、こちらに投稿させていただきました。